# parsing JSON response in Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I get a response from an OData service in the following JSON format

```
    [
       {
         "id":1,
         "ProductName":"Surface Pro 2" 
       },
       {
         "id":2,
         "ProductName":"iPad" 
       },
    ]
```

When I use angularjs to display I am doing

```
     <ion-item ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">
        {{product.ProductName}}
     </ion-item>
```

I am getting a blank screen. Somehow its not parsing the elements. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: is $scope.products in your controller set to the data?

Comment: have you assigned that data in `$scope.products`?

Comment: Yes when I just do {{product}} in my view I can see the entire JSON response, so I am setting the data to the scope variable. I had to use track by $index because it complained of ngRepeat:dupes.

Comment: anything in console?

Comment: @maddog I get an error if I remove the track by $index otherwise no error.

Comment: The actual error I am getting is Repeater:product in products, Duplicate key: string:",Duplicate value:". So is my products actually empty?

Comment: instead of `$index` try `product.id`. shouldnt affect it but...

Comment: @maddog Interesting. I tried track by product.Id and this time the error I got was Repeater:product in products track by product.Id, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value:{. Is there something in my JSON that is causing this issue? I have validated in JSONlint and its correct.

Comment: create a plunkr. it will give a better picture. plnkr.co if you dont know.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8edRgS8wNyEzO9ULz3db?p=catalogue Its not fully functional but all the pieces of my code is there.

Comment: In the console I observed $scope.products is an array of objects. Any thoughts how I could parse that to display?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. I iterated through the objects and pushed it into a local array. Now its working as required.